# SQL query with case and different conditions

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, case

I have a SQL database with a table looking more or less like this one:

```
channel  type  I1  I2 
    1     A    34   10
    2     A    27   9
    3     B    9    21
    1     A    29   11
    2     B    8    19
    3     A    27   9
    1     B    11   20
    2     B    9    22
    3     A    31   8
```

I would like to query the table using different criteria in case of `type=A` or `type=B`, however I would like to group the results by channel, showing the total hits.

My last approach to the problem is this: (not working)

```
SELECT  channel, count(channel)
case 
    when type="A" then
        WHERE I1>30 and I2<10 
    when type="B" then 
        WHERE I1>10 and I2<20 
end
from channelResults
group by channel
```

The expected output would be so simple as:

```
channel   count
   1         9
   2         20
   3         3
```

So as an example, the output would show that in channel 1 there are 9 rows (type A or type B it does not matter) that satisfy each condition, that means, for example we have 4 typeA that satisfy condition for typeA + 5 typeB that satisfy condition for typeB, so in total 9.

Comment: what is expected output

Comment: What should be the intended op?

Comment: Why `count` for `channel = 2` is 20 when there're *9 rows at all*?

Comment: because it is just an example, not real data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
    select channel, 
           count(channel)
      from channelResults
     where type = 'A' and I1 > 30 and I2 < 10 or
           type = 'B' and I1 > 10 and I2 < 20
  group by channel
```

but still i'm not sure if this is what you want as output, if it is not please be more specific.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  channel, --count(channel)
case when type="A" and I1>30 and I2<10 then count(channel) 
     when type="B" and I1>10 and I2<20 then count(channel)
end as count
from channelResults
group by channel
```

Answer (score 1):

There's multiple ways to write this. One way would be to split the query into 2 parts as that's really what your problem states -- one set of criteria for A, another for B.  So following that line of thinking:

```
select channel, count(channel) from (
  --countables type A
  select * from channelResults where type='A' and I1>30 and I2<10 
  union all
  --countables type B
  select * from channelResults where type='B' and I1>10 and I2<20 
) data
GROUP BY data.channel
```

Another way would be to output the count value (0 or 1) using a case, a bit like what you were doing, and then count (or sum) that colum:

```
SELECT  
  channel,
  count( --or sum()
    CASE 
      WHEN [type]='A' and I1>30 and I2<10 then 1 
      WHEN [type]='B' and I1>10 and I2<20 then 1 
      ELSE NULL 
    END 
  ) CountValue
FROM channelResults
GROUP BY channel
```

If this is a bit hard to check/decipher, you could also do this in multiple steps:

```
WITH count_data AS (
    SELECT  
      *, 
      CASE 
        WHEN [type]='A' and I1>30 and I2<10 then 1 
        WHEN [type]='B' and I1>10 and I2<20 then 1 
        ELSE NULL 
      END AS CountValue
    FROM channelResults
) 
SELECT channel, COUNT(CountValue) CountValue 
FROM count_data
GROUP BY channel
```

You can then initially write the bottom query as:

```
select * from count_data
```

Then once you're happy with how the raw data and how case works, you can then group it as I showed above.

Hope that helps.

Comment: that is a very good answer, thanks. Now that you gave 3 ways....which one would be the most efficient if my table was very big?? (not the case now, but just in case)

Comment: This would depend on the indexes available on your database and so on. That said, the first suggestion is likely IMHO to be quickest assuming suitable indexes on [type], I1 and I2 since this implies quick/efficient selection of the raw data (2 selects + union) followed by a count on a raw colum (as opposed to a count on an expression etc.)  But the best answer is for you to do some analysis (plan analysis, index analysis) on your particular database and determine what is in fact best in your context.

Comment: Just to add: lunaks' solution is likely going to be as efficient or better than the union suggestion I made.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a fiddle to play around with ... I was testing my SQL while all the other answered ;)

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fd13e/3

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:-

```
SELECT  channel, count(case when type="A" and I1>30 and I2<10 then channel end as count_channel
                            when type="B" and I1>10 and I2<20 then channel end as count_channel)
from channelResults
group by channel
```

Comment: seems like this one is not working, there is actually a parantheses open next to `count` but it is never closed